# Embedding a curve in projective space

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

In Hartshorne Chapter IV:

> **Corollary 3.6.** Any curve can be embedded in $\mathbb{P}^3$.

What is the precise definition of embedding here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The author means a closed embedding, also called a [closed immersion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_immersion).  So the precise statement is: given a curve $X$, there is a closed immersion $X \to \mathbb{P}^3$.  (This is clear from the two propositions immediately preceding the corollary.)